# Select field in Material-UI onMenuScrollToBottom property

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, select, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I'm using select field from Material-UI and I want when I scroll to the bottom of the menu to call an API to append some new options.

In `react-select` library there is a `onMenuScrollToBottom` property which is used for this reason but in the Material-UI select field I don't see such a prop. Do you know how can I implement this functionality? I'm using `import { SelectField } from 'redux-form-material-ui';`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MUI `Select` does not have `onMenuScrollToBottom` props, but you can listen to the `scroll` event and detect when the the user reaches the bottom using this simple code:

```js
<Select
  MenuProps={{
    PaperProps: {
      onScroll: (event) => {
        const listEl = event.currentTarget;
        if (
          listEl.scrollTop + listEl.clientHeight >=
          listEl.scrollHeight
        ) {
          console.log("scroll to bottom!");
        }
      }
    }
  }}
  {...props}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67090527/select-field-in-material-ui-onmenuscrolltobottom-property]